# Magento 2.2.3 white screen

Tags: error, magento2.2.3

First time here although I do read through the forums.

On Saturday night 3rd March I'm guessing I had an auto update to Magento 2.2.3, before this update everything had been working fine.
I am now getting a white screen on my home page and I can't access the admin area as that is also a white screen.
I haven't messed with any of the coding.

My error log shows:

> [05-Mar-2018 07:23:18 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend\Stdlib\Glob' not found in /home/bud/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Glob.php on line 14

I have tried searching this error but there are so many different answers and a lot of them from previous versions.

Any help would be greatful.

Cheers

Comment: Are you able to run cli commands?

Comment: did you run `composer update` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try Install php zend stdlib library

**sudo apt-get update**

**sudo apt-get install php-zend-stdlib**

After this restart apache

sudo service apache2 restart

If Issue persist try following commands

- Remove pub/static var/ generated
- sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- sudo chmod -R 777 pub/static var/ generated

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP are you using? If it's less than 5.0 then please update your PHP version to < 7.0 and check.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your feedback.
I can confirm we are on PHP7.1, all was working fine before the update.
I have now switched of the auto updates.

I had done a back up previously so have done a restore although this is now back up and running going forward I will need to look into this more for future updates etc.

Thank you.